# Problem to generate an abi to a struct that has two keys

Tags: smart-contract

I'm trying to generate an abi to a struct that has two keys 
I have tried different combination but could not have both indexes generated.
Has someone succeed trying something like that ?
Is this a know bug?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying get table rows with diferent table_keys using api or cleos, that feature is not working. You can see the code in https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/plugins/chain_plugin/include/eosio/chain_plugin/chain_plugin.hpp#L255. In that method the parameter `p.table_key` is never used.

Running the command like:
`cleos get table contract scope table -k customer -L 56`

the `customer` parameters is not used.

Comment: There are several issues on GitHub about this, including this one:  https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/3695